# sort swift array and keep track of original index

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I would to sort a swift array and keep track of the original indices.  For example:
arrayToSort = [1.2, 5.5, 0.7, 1.3]

indexPosition = [0, 1, 2, 3]

sortedArray = [5.5, 1.3, 1.2, 0.7]

indexPosition = [1, 3, 0, 2]

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: Are you maintaining two separate arrays?

Answer (score 10):

Easiest way is with enumerate. Enumerate gives each element in the array an index in the order they appear and you can then treat them separately.

```
let sorted = arrayToSort.enumerate().sort({$0.element > $1.element})
```

this results in [(.0 1, .1 5.5), (.0 3, .1 1.3), (.0 0, .1 1.2), (.0 2, .1 0.7)]

To get the indices sorted:

```
let justIndices = sorted.map{$0.index}   // [1, 3, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the answer from @twiz_ and I think the syntax changed a bit in Swift3 and I just verified the following code in playground. It works

```
let arrayToSort = [1.2, 5.5, 0.7, 1.3]
let sorted = arrayToSort.enumerated().sorted(by: {$0.element > $1.element}) // [(1, 5.5), (3, 1.3), (0, 1.2), (2, 0.69999999999999996)]
let justIndices = sorted.map{$0.offset} // [1, 3, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something along these lines

```
let arrayToSort =  [1.2, 5.5, 0.7, 1.3]
var oldIndices = [Int]()

let sortedArray = arrayToSort.sort { $0 > $1 }
var newIndices = [Int]()

for element in arrayToSort
{
    oldIndices.append(arrayToSort.indexOf(element)!)
    newIndices.append(sortedArray.indexOf(element)!)
}

print(oldIndices)
print(newIndices)
```

You could also use tuples.

```
var indices = [(Int,Int)]()
indices.append((arrayToSort.indexOf(element)!,sortedArray.indexOf(element)!))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by using a `struct` to keep up with the index position.

```
struct Foo {
    var value: Double
    var position: Int
}

let arrayToSort = [Foo(value: 1.2, position: 0), Foo(value: 5.5, position: 1), Foo(value: 0.7, position: 2), Foo(value: 1.3, position: 3)]
let sortedArray = arrayToSort.sorted { $0.value > $1.value }
let indexPosition = sortedArray.map { $0.position }
```